# How can I resolve the WooCommerce 'Error' and 'Warning: Illegal Characters' message within the WooCommerce files?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a WordPress website, with WooCommerce functionality.  The website has not gone live yet, as undergoing some testing.

I have just tested the Checkout process, and on the Checkout page, I see the following error message:

```
Error found in: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/libraries/class-wc-eval-math.php, nfx, 117 
Warning: illegal character '�' in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/libraries/class-wc-eval-math.php on line 289
```

These files have not been edited by myself and and I installed the WooCommerce directly from WooCommerce.

Anyone have any ideas on what this is and how I can resolve this?  I have not come across this error message before.

I am not sure if the issue is connected but the PayPal/Delivery section, on the Checkout page,generates the loading spinner, which stays on the page and does not load anything.

**EDIT:**
When making a purchase from within the UK, the 'Proceed to PayPal' button works fine.  It is only when I change the country, within the drop down menu,that the Spinner loads continually.  Thus preventing any progress.  I have looked at the 'Console' feature within Google Chrome and it highlights the following error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/css/custom-stylesheet.css?ver=1.0
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1    http://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    custom-stylesheet.css
```

I then went into the Page Source but could see that the above files had loaded.  Could the issue lie within this?

Comment: You have to remove them manually or just replace the files with the default one's if there is no customisation implemented on them...

Comment: The files have not been modified.  The error relates to the default WooCommerce files.

Comment: Have you tried to replaced your effected files with the new ones? If not then give it a try once..

Comment: Though the WooCommerce was only updated a few days ago,  I thought I would carry out your suggestion.  Unfortunately, the problem still persists.  I have looked through the WooCommerce System Report but no issues are presented.

Comment: Thanks for your time Amit Chauhan.  I have now resolved the issue, as per my answer below. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved!

I had placed the '£' in the 'Cost Field', when setting shipping costs.  I removed the '£' and the problem was resolved!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me too. Make sure to remove special characters from all shipping zones and shipping methods that are configured, as they all can have this negative effect.